# What are the instances where a Weekly Shounen Jump serialized manga would not be released in a given week?

Tags: manga-production, shonen-jump

What are the instances that there is no manga (like Naruto, Bleach and One Peace) release? Are there certain events that prevent them from releasing? Then what are these events (aside from taking a break)? Is there some sort of calendar of events for this?.

Comment: but we had claymore and fairy tail released this week. Are the publishers different for these?

Comment: Is there some sort of calendar of events for this?..:)

Comment: this question in this time of the year has been asked so many times in so many forums that now half of the world must know about golden week.

Comment: @Krazer Is this question about Shonen Jump (the defunct American magazine) or Weekly Shonen Jump (the still-published Japanese magazine)?

Comment: @senshin most likely the latter, so the excerpt does need to be change if we decide to keep using the tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to understand that the manga industry is in fact an industry and normal industry situations happen.

The reasons behind a manga not coming out can be the same reasons some shop or company does not work at certain periods of time, but more specifically I've seen the following:

- There is a public holiday for that period in the country of the publishing (e.g. Golden Week).
- The author of the manga is taking a break after a two-chapter release. (Which basically means that the author already did this weeks job last week)
- The author is on vacation.
- The author is on an unpaid leave due to reasons of his concern.
- The author is sick and cannot work due to that. (Pretty much calling in sick, in layman terms).

Any other reasons a normal person may not be able to work at a job all also apply here. If by chance there is a public holiday but a chapter still comes out, chances are the author prepared the chapter beforehand, and is enjoying the holiday like everyone else, although it appears that he was "working" that week.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by Miharu in the comments below, there also might be a rare situation where a manga which is based on a currently airing anime has caught up to the anime and therefore might take a break to let the anime progress a little further. (Personally I haven't seen this phenomenon though.)

Comment: Fair point but you should probably mention a scenario where perhaps e.g. the animes have already caught up to the mangas?

Comment: @MiharuDante Since the question appeared to be about mangas specifically, I addressed the problem from a manga industry point of view. What you described is probably more relevant to the anime industry as it could be the *anime* that has caught up to the manga and therefore has to either make filler episodes or stop airing until the manga progresses further. I personally haven't seen this issue in reversed situations (where the manga is based on the anime) but I'll add it to my answer non the less. Thanks.

Comment: I think the latter part is the other way around. Anime is giving manga version time to cope up with the current episode. One sign of this is an episode filler.

Answer (score 4):

The most typical reason is a scheduled vacation. Out of four weeks the year, Japan celebrates major holidays and festivities. Many schools take the week off as a holiday.

At the time of you question is the holiday called "Golden Week." These are the only times that the mangaka can take a scheduled break without taking a hiatus (e.g., taking off the next issue). They called preceding issue (before the break) is a "double issue." Now you may think that a double issue means that since the magazine is meant for a 2-week period, the contents are doubles. That's not the case here. What's implied is that there will be no Weekly Shonen Jump issue in the following week.

There is no Weekly Shonen Jump the last week of December (end of the year; Christmas), 2nd week of January (New Years holiday), first week of May ("Golden Week," a [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Week_%28Japan%29) of holidays), second week of August (Obon).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found out, something called a "[Golden week](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906005410/http://sleepinggeeks.com/2014/05/01/fairy-tail-383-naruto-675-one-piece-746-bleach-579/)".

Comment: while your link answers the question, in an occassion when the link is "dead" the answer will be rendered useless. Please include a quotation from the link in your answer and provide the link as an reference.

Comment: Actually this is just one. I am asking the instances that a manga is not released.