# When are the annual breaks for Weekly Shonen Jump?

Tags: manga-production

After looking for the new chapter of One Piece, I came across [this site](http://www.mcm.fr/one-piece-chapitre-757-naruto-chapitre-689-pas-de-mangas-aujourd-hui-a321571.html). Here they said

> The second week of august marks the annual summer break from the publisher Shueisha.

Remembering the golden week from begin May, it made me wonder what other annual breaks mangakas have and when we shouldn't expect a new release to come out.

Comment: This would be the answer I was looking for http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/9484/6166